# How dynamicly add input field from select option change

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select statements.  When I select an option, I need to then dynamically add input fields below, with option text from the select. Thanks for help.
This is what I have:

```
$('#tep_select').on('change',function(){

        if($('#tep_select').val() == 1){

                $('#tep_select_options').append('<input id="tep_select_options_'+1+'" type="text">');
            }else{
                $('#tep_select_options_'+1+'').remove();


 }});
```

How can the input control dynamically get its text label from the select's options?

Comment: How is this not working? Please clarify your question above. Also, spellcheck is your friend.

Comment: Values from an input field will be strings. Try adding single quotes around your 1: if( $('#tep_select' ).val() == '1' { ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#tep_select").on("change", function(){

    if($(this).val() === "1") {
        $("<input>")
            .attr("id", "tep_select_options_1")
            .attr("type", "text")
            .val($(this).text())
            .appendTo("#tep_select_options");
    }
    else {
        $("#tep_select_options_"+$(this).val()).remove();
    }

});
```

Comment: .attr("id", "tep_select_options_1") could be changed to .attr("id","tep_select_options_" + $(this).val()), no hardcoding needed. Also, $("#tep_select_options_"+$(this).val()).remove(); needs to be  $("#tep_select_options_1").remove() to remove the element.

Comment: But why have the extra lookup when you know the value will always be 1?

Comment: so that in the future, you don't need to hardcode it for other value checks ;)

Comment: I see your point, but generally don't like to take performance hits (albeit, a minor one in this case) for something that will likely never happen. If another value check is needed, they will need to code it under another if statement anyway.